# Error when sending report from sales cloud

Tags: reporting, marketing-cloud-connect, error-messages, sales-cloud

I have been trying to send an email containing Lead Report from sales cloud. The email when received shows the message "Failed" with an error report in the body. The error states "Error retrieving data".
I followed the steps for sending report from trailhead. Linking the document here:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-connect/test-the-connection?trail_id=use-marketing-cloud-connect

If anyone has any idea as to why I am receiving this error, please help me out[image: Image containing the error message]

Answer (score 0):

the error because the Mc integration in SFMC is not able to access your report

1. Please check all permissions
2. are there a access policies or transaction polices being applied if, yes disable them